# How to run SQL Developer in debug mode

Tags: oracle, debugging, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wish to run my Oracle Procedure in SQL Developer Debug Mode.

I understand this requires running the following scripts on the database as SYS

```
    GRANT DEBUG CONNECT SESSION TO myschema;
    GRANT DEBUG ANY PROCEDURE TO myschema;


BEGIN
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_HOST_ACE
(
host => '142.168.XXX.XXX',
lower_port => null,
upper_port => null,
ace => xs$ace_type(privilege_list => xs$name_list('jdwp'),
principal_name => 'myschema',
principal_type => xs_acl.ptype_db)
);
END;
```

For the HOST do I put my laptop IP4 address ( get with ipconfig ) or that of the remote data base ?

I've added the remote TNS entry to TNSNames.ora

```
racmbdevi_1=
(DESCRIPTION=
(ADDRESS=
(PROTOCOL=TCP)
(HOST=10.36.XXX.XXX)
(PORT=1532)
)
(CONNECT_DATA=
(SERVICE_NAME=MBDEVI)
(INSTANCE_NAME=racmbdev_1)
)
)
```

if I try the remote DBase address I get..

```
Connecting to the database auditcollections@RAC-MBDEV.
Executing PL/SQL: ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_DEBUG=TRUE
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( '10.36.XXX.XXX', '4000' )
ORA-30683: failure establishing connection to debugger
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP", line 68
ORA-06512: at line 1
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database auditcollections@RAC-MBDEV.
```

if I try my laptop IP4 address It connects I guess and the procedure runs since I get output messages
however it deosn't run to my breakpoint so I could step through it.

What am I missing out on... how can I in fact run in debug mode and step through a procdure ?

```
Connecting to the database auditcollections@RAC-MBDEV.
Executing PL/SQL: ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_DEBUG=TRUE
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( '142.168.XXX.XXX', '4000' )
Debugger accepted connection from database on port 4000.
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.DISCONNECT()
===>>>> p_note_log1 = NEXIUM 40MG TABLET- NO SUB 
===>>>> p_note_log1 = 
===>>>> p_note_log1 = 
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database auditcollections@RAC-MBDEV.
Debugger disconnected from database.
```

Comment: Jeff Smith, the product manager, who is active here does have a blog entry on setting up debugging for compiled plsql blocks here, https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/02/how-to-start-the-plsql-debugger/.